# how to embed an image in an vsto addin for outlook in c#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have made an outlook 2013 vsto application for appointments.the application sets text in the appointment body using

```
currentAppointment.Body
```

Now i want to set an image to the appointment body.one idea ive got is to use the

```
currentAppointment.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

or using the clipboard

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage();
```

but i didn't  find any workable examples in this case.
any idea how it can be done
Thanks.

Comment: You were on the right track with the GetInspector

Answer (score 0):

First add a reference to Word in your project

[image]

Then this code will add an inline image to the body of a new appointment.

```
    public void NewAppointment(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem currentAppointment = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
            currentAppointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            currentAppointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
            currentAppointment.Location = "ConferenceRoom #1";
            currentAppointment.Body = "Body of event...";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docx = currentAppointment.GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
            if (docx != null)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selected = docx.Windows[1].Selection;
                docx.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"c:\temp\test.jpg");
            }

            currentAppointment.AllDayEvent = false;
            currentAppointment.Subject = "Group Project";
            currentAppointment.Save();
            currentAppointment.Display(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```